# Force updateSelectizeInput to trigger on change event

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

this is my app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr) 
data <- mtcars

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        selectizeInput("cyl", "MPG", choices = c(4, 6, 8), selected = 6),
        selectizeInput("carb", "Carb", choices = c(1,2,3,4), selected = c(1,2,3), multiple = TRUE),
        uiOutput("carbui")
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        dataTableOutput("dt"),
        textOutput("carbsoutput")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

    # filtereddata <-  reactive({
    filtereddata <-  eventReactive(input$carb, {

        req(input$carb)
        data <- data %>%
            filter(cyl == input$cyl) %>%
            filter(carb %in% input$carb)
        data
    })

    output$dt <- renderDataTable({
        print("reactive was triggered")
        filtereddata()
    })


    observeEvent(input$cyl, {

        print("observer was triggered")

        vals <- switch(input$cyl,
                       "4" = c(1,2,3),
                       "6" = c(1,2,3,4),
                       "8" = c(1,2,3))

        updateSelectizeInput(session, "carb", "Carb", choices = vals, selected = vals)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I tried to achieve is that the table does not get double-rendered when I update `input$cyl`, which happens when I switch `input$cyl`from 4 to 6 without eventReactive. But the problem is, when I now switch `input$cyl` from 4 to 8, the `eventReactive` does not get triggered, since `input$carb` does not get updated. Is there a way to FORCE the updateSelectizeInput to update so that the other events get always triggered?

Comment: you can watch both inputs like this `eventReactive(c(input$carb, input$cyl), {...})` so any changes to `input$cyl` will trigger the data filtering too

Comment: When I do this, and switch input$cyl from 4 to 6, the reactive gets triggered twice and the table renders twice. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem :-(

Comment: You have coded yourself into a very strange corner, you have an observe event triggered by `input$cyl`, this in turn updates the input to another input, `input$carb` which is supposed to trigger an event reactive based on a change to `input$carb` where the values come from `input$cyl` which might not be unique when the input to `input$cyl` is changed since two options are equal. Which is why the trigger is not responding. I would take @Nate 's advice and reconfigure your reactive statements to run all code based on a change to either input once with a render function at the end.

Comment: Puh, everything else triggers the rendering of my table at least 2 times. My only problem is the lazy evaluation of the reactive expression :-(